How to disable the browser remembering what's entered on a form on navigation
We have a login form on our page with the standard username and password fields. If the user fills out the form, then navigates away, I would expect that the browser would forget the password field for security purposes. However, as the user hits the back button, they can get back to the login page and the browser preserves that username/password. This was reported as an issue on our Bug Bounty, that using a shared computer could expose credentials to another person. While unlikely, we do have a common use case of multiple people using a shared computer (classrooms where the teacher and students all use the same machine).
How can we ensure that the browser's behavior does not preserve the password field in the history's memory? For some reason we had the idea that Cache-Control: no-cache would prevent it, but that didn't seem to work. I do not want to do something like autocomplete='off' or Javascript to clear the field on load. We still want saved passwords and password managers to still work to promote good password habits.
